# Tooltip styling in django

Tags: django, tooltip

In my registration page i have tool-tip for password showing the format that user should enter."Password must contain at least 10 characters,including UPPER/lowercase, numbers and special characters"
 I want to know how to style this tool-tip such that 1st line text should end with "....10 characters" and second line should start with "including..." Also I want to apply font,size color to this text.

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", "password")

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Username', 'required':'','autofocus':''})
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password', 'required':'','data-html':'true','title':'Password must contain at least 8 characters,'
     'including UPPER/lowercase, numbers and special characters.','data-toggle':'tooltip', 'data-placement':'right'})
```

Comment: this kind of specific formatting should be done in the template that renders the form.

Comment: @warath-coder my template looks like this. how should i wrote tool-tip now?       {% for field in form %}
                {{ field }}  
              {% endfor %}

Comment: jquery, and whatever tooltip library you want to use (bootstraps, qtip2, etc).

Comment: I agree that styling your tooltip should be done in CSS